# Subsonic 2.2 Binding joined table columns to a grid

Tags: subsonic

I am still reasonably new to subsonic and finding the simplest things a little tricky.
I have a simple query that joins two tables, Profile and Subscription.

```
  ProfileCollection profiles =
            new Select().From<Profile>()
                .InnerJoin(Subscription.ProfileIdColumn,Profile.ProfileIDColumn )
                .Where(Subscription.ExpiryDateColumn).IsLessThan(Date)
                .ExecuteAsCollection <ProfileCollection > ();
        return profiles;
```

I want to display the following columns in my grid, Profile.Name and Subscription.ExpiryDate and maybe a few others.

Previously I have used LLBLGen and I could do something like (please note this is pseudo code):

```
<repeater>    
<itemitemplate>

<%#Eval("Name")%>
<%#Eval("Subscription.ExpiryDate")%>  
</itemitemplate>   

</repeater>
```

But I get an error something along the lines of

> Subscription isnt a member of
>   Profile

I tried updating my query so it had the column names in the select, but I also got the above error.

```
     ProfileCollection profiles =
                new Select(Subscription.ExpiryDateColumn.PropertyName,
Profile.NameColumn.PropertyName).From<Profile>()
                    .InnerJoin(Subscription.ProfileIdColumn,Profile.ProfileIDColumn )
                    .Where(Subscription.ExpiryDateColumn).IsLessThan(Date)
                    .ExecuteAsCollection <ProfileCollection > ();
            return profiles;
```

It seems like something really common and I am finding multiple places where I need to bind to a grid and call columns from the joining table but it doesn't seem possible.

Can someone either tell me what I'm missing or let me know the best way to bind joined table rows to grids with subsonic?

**My Solution**
Ok from the answers below I have established I need to do the following: 
I have used * so I can bring back all rows

```
 Dataset profiles =
                new Select("Subscription.*","Profile.*").From<Profile>()
                    .InnerJoin(Subscription.ProfileIdColumn,Profile.ProfileIDColumn )
                    .Where(Subscription.ExpiryDateColumn).IsLessThan(Date)
                    .ExcecuteDataset();
            return profiles;
```

In my grid I can now bind <%#Eval("Name")%> from the profile table and <%#Eval(Subscription.ExpiryDate")%> from subscription to my grid

**Any more suggestions?** Even though the above works I am not happy using "Subscription.*",   "Profile.*" in the select, I'd rather use some strongly typed values incase something changes so I get compile errors rather than it just crashing out when it tries and runs the query!

Thanks

Bex

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at the [SubSonic Query Tool](http://subsonicproject.com/docs/Simple_Query_Tool) to perform joins, the attached link has a lot of sample that should help.  If you have to do complex joins with SubSonic, I suggest you move the logic to a stored procedure.  Below, will create a query that returns the colums you list in the Select() method.

Example:

```
SqlQuery q = new Select(Subscription.ExpiryDateColumn.PropertyName, Profile.NameColumn.PropertyName).From<Profile>()
                    .InnerJoin(Subscription.ProfileIdColumn,Profile.ProfileIDColumn )
                    .Where(Subscription.ExpiryDateColumn).IsLessThan(Date);

DataTable dt = q.ExecuteDataSet().Tables[0];
```

Comment: I am using the subsonic query tool above (aren't I?) but I am still returning a collection (of type Profile in this case) so I still cannot work out how to bind them to a grid as I get the same errors as above! Should it be returning something else?
I'd rather steer clear of SPs if I can help it but so far I am not having problems doing the actual joins, it's just the binding the results from the joined table to a grid. Can you give any examples of how I'd do this?

Comment: You can bind a SubSonic query results as a DataTable, Reader, or Collection.  If you want a strongly typed collection, use the collections Load() method and pass in the query (see example above).

Comment: Will your above example allow me access to <%#eval("Subscription.ExpiryDate"%> when I bind to my grid?

Comment: No, it will only give you the properties available in the ProfileCollection.  Collections are strongly typed, you can't add new properties to them.  If you want to mix and match columns, you need to use the SqlQuery and pick your columns by adding the columns to the Select(<table>.<column>,<table>.<column>) function call.

Comment: That was my original question..!
I have tried adding table.column to the select but as it's bringing back a profile collection it's only seeing the profile columns! I assume I need to return a dataset then?

Comment: I have added how I've got it working above but it's not really how I'd like it to so if you have other suggestions let me know.

Comment: Gotcha... Guess I was confused with the code/question, I updated the example to pull back the data into a DataTable using a query.  You could pull it back into other objects as well, but for the sake of simplicity I used a DataTable.

Comment: :) thanks! Got there in the end! You don't happen to know how to do the select * without actually putting * in quotes do you?

Comment: If you want everything from both tables you can enter "*" (with quotes) or you can list all the columns inline (e.g. Subscription.Columns.ExpiryDate, Profile.Columns.Name).  Your creating a dynamic result set that is not tied to a collection, so your going to have to do a little work to get the data you need.